# Figure with tabular environment

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am trying to create a figure a table, that is, with `tabular` on it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,
            right=20mm,
            bottom=30mm,
            top=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol} 
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,longtable}


% Rotated text inside tables
\newcommand{\spheading}[2][1]{% \spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}
    \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#1}{\centering #2}}
}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c*3{l}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.1\linewidth}}{Block Method}
        & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}{EIT} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}{mSDT} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}{SLT} \\ \hline
        \spheading[7em]{\small $N_b = 2$}
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-a}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-b}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-c}
        } \\ \hline
          \spheading[7em]{\small $N_b = 4$}
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-a}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-b}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-c}
        } \\ \hline
          \spheading[7em]{\small $N_b = 5$}
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-a}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-b}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=0.41]{example-image-c}
        }\\ \hline
        \spheading[7em]{\small $N_b = 10$}
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-a}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-b}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-c}
        } \\ \hline
        \spheading[7em]{\small $N_b = 20$}
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-a}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-b}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-c}
        } \\ \hline
        \spheading[7em]{\small $N_b = 40$}
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-a}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-b}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-c}
        } \\ \hline
        \spheading[7em]{\small $N_b = 50$}
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-a}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-b}
        }
        & \raisebox{-.5em}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=.41]{example-image-c}
        } \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example.}
    \label{fig:BlockComparison_MatDist_pa=12}
\end{figure}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

As a result, I have:

[image]

I would like to know how to:

- align the text of the first column;
- increase the length of each row (so the figure is not glued to each horizontal line, and
- split this figure into two pages.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Why rotating the items in the first column?

Comment: This is not necessary, but since I don't know how to vertically align it, I found this solution easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you want to rotate the items in the first column.

I'd not use `scale`, preferring to set a width. The spaces above and below the rules can be obtained with `\midrule` and setting the vertical space above rules the same as below (by default it's not needed).

For vertically centering the images, use `valign=c`, provided by `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  left=20mm,
  right=20mm,
  bottom=30mm,
  top=30mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{\belowrulesep}

\begin{tabular}{@{} cccc @{} }
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Block Method} \\
 \cmidrule(l){2-4}
 & EIT & mSDT & SLT \\
\midrule
$N_b = 2$
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-c} \\
\midrule
$N_b = 4$
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-c} \\
\midrule
$N_b = 5$
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-c} \\
\midrule
$N_b = 10$
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-c} \\
\midrule
$N_b = 20$
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-c} \\
\midrule
$N_b = 40$
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-c} \\
\midrule
$N_b = 50$
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}
  & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-c} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Example.}
\label{fig:BlockComparison_MatDist_pa=12}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You also need no `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, because settings done inside `figure` are local. For instance, the value of `\aboverulesep` will be restored after `\end{figure}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. I never paid too much attention to the differences between `\hline` and `\toprule`. I have two questions though: (1) what `\setlength{\aboverulesep}{\belowrulesep}` does?, and (2) what is the idea when using `@{}}` in `\begin{tabular}{@{} cccc @{}}`?

Comment: @AndréXavier The first column usually has some padding (`\tabcolsep` wide), but most often this is not needed, like in this case; similarly after the last column. A `\midrule` has `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulespace` around it; the standard values are different (less space above than below) for various reasons, but in this case they must be equal.

Comment: Do know how can I split this figure into two pages? Of course, I can change the figure size. However, by doing that the figure information will be too small! I know there are packages such as `longtable`, `supertabular`, `xtab` and others, but I am not familiar with any of them, and I don't know which one is the best -- at least, in my case.

Comment: @AndréXavier You want `longtable`.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg.